# Validate null object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

In order to validate if model comes null or not I use something like this:

```
  if (model is null || !model.Any()) return this;
```

But in latest Microsoft conference I saw guys use something like:

```
    if(model is { })
```

I try to use it but always return true (if object comes null or not)

So my question is. Is there a new way to check if a model comes null?
What is the correct usage of brackets `{ }`

Note: I googled about that brackets but I found anything. Regards

Comment: With .NET Core 3.0, C# 8, `model is {}` returns false for me when `model` is null. It's behaving identically to `model is object`, though perhaps there's somethign I haven't though of testing. It's difficult to persuade Google of what I'm searching for.

Comment: And what about if model exists but `Count = 0`, whe should use `if (model is { } || !model.Any()) return this;` ? @EdPlunkett

Comment: If your intent was expressed by `if (model is null || !model.Any()) return this;`, that is, if you want to return `this` when your model is null or empty, then keep that code. It's clear and idiomatic and won't throw any exceptions. You could say `if !((model is {}) || !model.Any()) return this;`, but that just be harder to read. Don't use new language features if they don't add clarity.

Comment: Or use Guilherme's `model?.Any() != true` formulation, if you want to use a relatively modern language feature.

Comment: If you want "model exists but count is zero", that's `if (model is {} && !model.Any())` -- and, not or.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a generic extension method to check if your object is null or not.

Try:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) { 
   return source?.Any() != true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check for `NullOrEmpty` is to coerce `Count()` to an `int?`. Then we can compare the result of `GetValueOrDefault` to `0`:

```
if((model?.Count).GetValueOrDefault() == 0) return this;
```

How it works:

- Because the `?.` operator will return `null` if the left side is `null`, and `Count` returns an `int`, the result of `(model?.Count)` is a `Nullable<int>`.
- The `GetValueOrDefault` method returns the value of `Count` if `model` is not `null`, otherwise it returns `default(int)` (which is `0`).
- This way if `model` is `null`, the condition returns `0`